# _setupDecimals() – undefined identifier

Tags: openzeppelin

I'm trying to specify the amount of decimals of a token using OpenZeppelin. This will cause a compilation error:

```js
import {ERC20} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MyToken is ERC20 {
   //........

   constructor() ERC20("my token", "a")  {
       // _mint(..... )
     _setupDecimals(4); //  – undefined identifier
 }

//.........
```

What's the matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_setupDecimals` is not a function of the normal OpenZepplin ERC20 contract.

To change the decimals you can override the [`decimals`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L87-L89) function and return another value.

Edit: This is also mentioned in the [constructor documentation of the ERC20 contract](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L87-L89):

> The default value of {decimals} is 18. To select a different value for {decimals} you should overload it.